# What is "a public key under ECIES", and how to get it?

Tags: web3js, parity, encryption

I read the JSONRPC document of Parity these days.

And I want to encrypt my message with the public key and private key of the accounts in Parity.

I found a JSONRPC in this web [parity_encryptMessage](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_decryptmessage)

But it refers that

> "Encrypt some data with a public key under ECIES."

And one of its parameters is

> "Hash - Public EC key generated with secp256k1 curve, truncated to the
>   last 64 bytes."

I can't understand it. I don't know how to get it. It generate by Parity or it should generate by myself? Please give me some advice. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECIES is the *Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme*. You should not wrap your head around the terminology too much, this is basically the crypto behind all Ethereum keypairs.

To generate a new keypair you can use [ethkey](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/tree/master/ethkey#generate-brain-seed).

```
 $ ethkey generate random
secret:  f302ecc87edbd4575bbe9bd8cbdaad3470191dad232c6df47cc294af084c15b7
public:  0bec09505ad3ac5e5a2562b43393938648dfaa4c60280ee8d1f6d00e5fbbbf422b3fb64d29ba56b4c2595b48202d9fd75375839b3b40886370cf5a559e374a81
address: fb80f51c9006a8eb3804821053305130d823c35a
```

Ethkey comes bundled with any Parity installation. Let's generate a brain wallet from your nick. Do not use this on public network:

```
$ ethkey generate brain YangYifei
secret:  c3d09aa314f216b618c84b3592d4d6992096ad544158a511148450771882c16e
public:  8b22ba82b80cb8d9e5e6207cbd8039bdb84398aaa63e5dd0684786456cd69a7708d334c92c540ed1d1764736b51fdcb5b7b95540cc8663851a03da99862e305e
address: 0052afd86e17e4cf7163a619a4cc9724dd04506c
```

The public key you are looking for is `0x8b22...` above (64 bytes).

Comment: Note that the info about truncation to 64 bytes arises when public keys are specified as ASN.1 encoded 'uncompressed'. A prefix byte is used to indicate that the value is compressed or not. If this prefix is 0x04, the total byte length is 65 bytes, with the following 64 being the public key. The public key is actually 2 numbers, each of 32 bytes, being the coordinates on an elliptic curve. These coordinates are used to mathematical operations to sign things, encrypt things etc.